Problem with I2S and IIR-filter
I am working on a system that receives audio data over Bluetooth using a BM83. This is transmitted to an STM32F7 over ADC, an IIR-filter is applied and the data is transmitted out over I2S. The ADC data is 12 bit right aligned, and the channels run on 88kHz Fs (4x I2S Fs), so every 4 data samples are averaged into one. For the I2S-out channel, communication standard is MSB, and format 16 bits data on 16 bit frame.
This part works, but what i want to do is replace the ADC that uses 12 bits with I2S using 16 bits.
So far i have been able to produce good, clear sound using I2S, but when i try to apply the IIR-filter that was working fine with the previous ADC implementation, the sound gets very noisy.
I am using CubeIDE. The I2S-out is same as above. I2S-in is set to I2S Philips (from what i read this is basically MSB anyway), and 44kHz Fs (have been unable to get proper sound at 22k, not sure if because of BM83, phone, Spotify or something else), so similiar to before every 2 samples are averaged into one.
To try and resemble the data format from the ADC implementation, after I2S data is received, i subtract an offset to center the data around 0 (-32768 to 32768), divide by 16 (turn 16bit into 12bit), and pass it to the exact same filter as before. After the filter, i multiply to restore the data to 16bit, and restore the offset making the data values range from 0-65536. But, this gives me noisy audio. Can anyone think of a reason this may be?
I have done various testing and here are a few noteworthy/strange things i have noticed:
When NOT using the filter, dividing by 16, then multiplying by 16 gives good audio, div 16 and mult 8 works, but mult with anything else (4, 2, 1) causes noise, and disables the use of the volume buttons on my phone.
I have also tried passing 16bit data to the filter, with and without offset subtracted, but this did not do any good.
Let me know if any further details would help.
Edit 1: Here is the (i think) relevant code.
Copying in data to left/right process buffer is handled in the RxCallback. The first Rx that eventually takes us here is started as part of an init function.
void HAL_I2S_RxCpltCallback(I2S_HandleTypeDef *hi2s)
{
    LL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOD, PD13_Pin);
    HAL_I2S_Receive_DMA(&hi2s3, input_i2s_buff[1 - i2s_buff_current], BUFFER_SIZE_INPUT);

    for(int i = 0, j = 0, t = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE_INPUT; i+=4){
        temp_in[t] = (((float32_t)input_i2s_buff[i2s_buff_current][i]) - 32768);
        process_buffer_input_left_float[j] = temp_in[t] / factor;
        temp_in[t+1] = (((float32_t)input_i2s_buff[i2s_buff_current][i+1]) - 32768);
        process_buffer_input_right_float[j] = temp_in[t+1] / factor;
        j++;
        t+=2;
    }

    flg_ready_to_process_left = 1;
    flg_ready_to_process_right = 1;
}

The filter processes and places data in output buffers. (This part i have not modified.)
void IIR_audio_filter_affect(){
    int i;

    // Initiate output buffers with '0'
    memset(IIR_f32_output_right, 0, sizeof(IIR_f32_output_right));
    memset(IIR_f32_output_left, 0, sizeof(IIR_f32_output_left));

    // Initiate temporary buffers with '0'
    memset(IIR_f32_output_temp_right, 0, sizeof(IIR_f32_output_temp_right));
    memset(IIR_f32_output_temp_left, 0, sizeof(IIR_f32_output_temp_left));

    //LL_GPIO_SetOutputPin(LED_RED_GPIO_Port, LED_RED_Pin); //-------------------------------LED ON-------------------------------

    for(i=0; i<BUFFER_SIZE_OUTPUT; i++){
        
        if (IIR_filterbank_right_enable) {

            // IIR filterbank right channel
            IIR_f32_output_temp_right[0][i] = IIR_4(&IIR_4_instance_lp_right, process_buffer_input_right_float[i]) * audio_dsp_gains[0];
            IIR_f32_output_temp_right[1][i] = IIR_8(&IIR_8_instance_right[0], process_buffer_input_right_float[i]) * audio_dsp_gains[1];
            IIR_f32_output_temp_right[2][i] = IIR_8(&IIR_8_instance_right[1], process_buffer_input_right_float[i]) * audio_dsp_gains[2];
            IIR_f32_output_temp_right[3][i] = IIR_8(&IIR_8_instance_right[2], process_buffer_input_right_float[i]) * audio_dsp_gains[3];
            IIR_f32_output_temp_right[4][i] = IIR_8(&IIR_8_instance_right[3], process_buffer_input_right_float[i]) * audio_dsp_gains[4];
            IIR_f32_output_temp_right[5][i] = IIR_8(&IIR_8_instance_right[4], process_buffer_input_right_float[i]) * audio_dsp_gains[5];

            IIR_f32_output_right[i] = IIR_f32_output_temp_right[0][i] + IIR_f32_output_temp_right[1][i] + IIR_f32_output_temp_right[2][i]
                                    + IIR_f32_output_temp_right[3][i] + IIR_f32_output_temp_right[4][i] + IIR_f32_output_temp_right[5][i];

            //IIR_f32_output_right[i] = process_buffer_input_right_float[i];

        } else {
            //IIR Lowpass for filtering quantization noise
            IIR_f32_output_right[i] = IIR_4(&IIR_4_instance_Q_right, process_buffer_input_right_float[i]) * AUDIO_OUTPUT_GAIN_RIGHT;
        }

        if (IIR_filterbank_left_enable) {

            // IIR filterbank left channel
            IIR_f32_output_temp_left[0][i] = IIR_4(&IIR_4_instance_lp_left, process_buffer_input_left_float[i]) * audio_dsp_gains[6];
            IIR_f32_output_temp_left[1][i] = IIR_8(&IIR_8_instance_left[0], process_buffer_input_left_float[i]) * audio_dsp_gains[7];
            IIR_f32_output_temp_left[2][i] = IIR_8(&IIR_8_instance_left[1], process_buffer_input_left_float[i]) * audio_dsp_gains[8];
            IIR_f32_output_temp_left[3][i] = IIR_8(&IIR_8_instance_left[2], process_buffer_input_left_float[i]) * audio_dsp_gains[9];
            IIR_f32_output_temp_left[4][i] = IIR_8(&IIR_8_instance_left[3], process_buffer_input_left_float[i]) * audio_dsp_gains[10];
            IIR_f32_output_temp_left[5][i] = IIR_8(&IIR_8_instance_left[4], process_buffer_input_left_float[i]) * audio_dsp_gains[11];

            IIR_f32_output_left[i] = IIR_f32_output_temp_left[0][i] + IIR_f32_output_temp_left[1][i] + IIR_f32_output_temp_left[2][i]
                                   + IIR_f32_output_temp_left[3][i] + IIR_f32_output_temp_left[4][i] + IIR_f32_output_temp_left[5][i];

            //IIR_f32_output_left[i] = process_buffer_input_left_float[i];

        } else {
            // IIR Lowpass for filtering quantization noise
            IIR_f32_output_left[i] = IIR_4(&IIR_4_instance_Q_left, process_buffer_input_left_float[i]) * AUDIO_OUTPUT_GAIN_LEFT;
        }
    }
    //LL_GPIO_ResetOutputPin(LED_RED_GPIO_Port, LED_RED_Pin); //-------------------------------LED OFF------------------------------

//  HAL_Delay(36);
}

In the programs while(1), offset and factor is restored (mult and factor are both 16), and placed in an output buffer which is continuously transmitted:
                    /*BLUETOOTH ACTIVE*/
                    }else{
                        for(i=0,j=0; i<BUFFER_SIZE_I2S; i+=2){
                            temp_out[i] = IIR_f32_output_left[j] * mult;
                            output_i2s_buff[i2s_buff_current][i] = (uint16_t)(temp_out[i] + offset_out);
                            temp_out[i+1] = IIR_f32_output_right[j] * mult;
                            output_i2s_buff[i2s_buff_current][i+1] = (uint16_t)(temp_out[i+1] + offset_out);
                            j++;
                        }
                    }


Schematics and source code would help.

What does "transmitted over ADC" mean?

Perhaps transmitted was the wrong word, but what i mean is the STM reads ADC data from the BM83 pins AOHPL/R (analog output headphone L/R).
